Can a Queue with Fewer Serves outperform a Queue with More Servers?
I am working on simulating an MMK queue with the following parameters:
lambda <- 5  # Arrival rate
mu <- 1      # Service rate
sim_time <- 200  # Simulation time
k_minutes <- 15  # Threshold for waiting time
num_simulations <- 100  # Number of simulations to run
initial_queue_size <- 100  # Initial queue size
time_step <- 1  # Time step for discretization

I simulated this code in R for 3 Servers vs 4 Servers:
  library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(gridExtra)

lambda <- 5  
mu <- 1      
sim_time <- 200  
k_minutes <- 15 
num_simulations <- 100  
initial_queue_size <- 100  
time_step <- 1  
k_values <- c(3, 4) 

run_simulation <- function(seed, k) {
    set.seed(seed)
    
    events <- data.frame(
        time = c(0, cumsum(rexp(ceiling(sim_time * lambda), rate = lambda))),
        type = "arrival"
    )
    events <- events[events$time <= sim_time, ]
    
    queue <- numeric(initial_queue_size)  # Initialize queue with initial_queue_size
    servers <- numeric(k)
    processed <- 0
    waiting_times <- numeric()
    
    results <- data.frame(
        time = seq(0, sim_time, by = time_step),
        queue_length = initial_queue_size,
        processed_orders = 0,
        waiting_longer = 0,
        total_arrivals = initial_queue_size
    )
    
    event_index <- 1
    for (i in 1:nrow(results)) {
        current_time <- results$time[i]
        
        # Process events up to current time
        while (event_index <= nrow(events) && events$time[event_index] <= current_time) {
            event_time <- events$time[event_index]
            
            # Process completed services
            finished <- servers <= event_time
            if (any(finished)) {
                processed <- processed + sum(finished)
                servers[finished] <- 0
            }
            
            # Process new arrival
            results$total_arrivals[i] <- results$total_arrivals[i] + 1
            if (any(servers == 0)) {
                free_server <- which(servers == 0)[1]
                servers[free_server] <- event_time + rexp(1, mu)
                waiting_times <- c(waiting_times, 0)
            } else {
                queue <- c(queue, event_time)
            }
            
            # Update queue
            while (length(queue) > 0 && any(servers == 0)) {
                free_server <- which(servers == 0)[1]
                wait_time <- event_time - queue[1]
                waiting_times <- c(waiting_times, wait_time)
                servers[free_server] <- event_time + rexp(1, mu)
                queue <- queue[-1]
            }
            
            event_index <- event_index + 1
        }
        
        results$queue_length[i] <- length(queue)
        results$processed_orders[i] <- processed
        results$waiting_longer[i] <- sum(waiting_times > k_minutes)
    }
    
    results
}

run_simulations <- function(k_values) {
    map(k_values, function(k) {
        map(1:num_simulations, ~run_simulation(., k)) %>%
            set_names(paste0("sim_", 1:num_simulations))
    }) %>% set_names(paste0("k", k_values))
}

simulations <- run_simulations(k_values)

process_results <- function(simulations) {
    map_dfr(names(simulations), function(k_name) {
        k <- as.integer(gsub("k", "", k_name))
        bind_rows(simulations[[k_name]], .id = "simulation") %>%
            mutate(k = k, simulation = as.integer(gsub("sim_", "", simulation))) %>%
            group_by(simulation, k) %>%
            mutate(
                cumulative_waiting_longer = cumsum(waiting_longer),
                cumulative_total_arrivals = cumsum(total_arrivals),
                waiting_percentage = pmin(100, pmax(0, (cumulative_waiting_longer / cumulative_total_arrivals) * 100))
            ) %>%
            ungroup()
    })
}

all_results <- process_results(simulations)

plot_waiting_percentage <- function(data, k) {
    ggplot(data %>% filter(k == !!k), aes(x = time, y = waiting_percentage, group = simulation)) +
        geom_line(alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
        stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1), color = "red", size = 1) +
        labs(title = paste("Percentage of People Waiting >", k_minutes, "Minutes (k=", k, ")"),
             subtitle = paste("Arrival Rate =", lambda, ", Service Rate =", mu),
             x = "Time", y = "Percentage") +
        theme_minimal() +
        ylim(0, 100)
}

plot_queue_length <- function(data, k) {
    ggplot(data %>% filter(k == !!k), aes(x = time, y = queue_length, group = simulation)) +
        geom_line(alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
        stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1), color = "red", size = 1) +
        labs(title = paste("Queue Length Over Time (k=", k, ")"),
             subtitle = paste("Arrival Rate =", lambda, ", Service Rate =", mu, ", Initial Queue Size =", initial_queue_size),
             x = "Time", y = "Queue Length") +
        theme_minimal() +
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))  # Start y-axis from 0
}

plot_cumulative_orders <- function(data, k) {
    ggplot(data %>% filter(k == !!k), aes(x = time, y = processed_orders, group = simulation)) +
        geom_line(alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
        stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1), color = "red", size = 1) +
        labs(title = paste("Cumulative Orders Processed (k=", k, ")"),
             subtitle = paste("Arrival Rate =", lambda, ", Service Rate =", mu, ", Initial Queue Size =", initial_queue_size),
             x = "Time", y = "Cumulative Orders") +
        theme_minimal() +
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))  
}

plots <- map(k_values, function(k) {
    list(
        waiting_percentage = plot_waiting_percentage(all_results, k),
        queue_length = plot_queue_length(all_results, k),
        cumulative_orders = plot_cumulative_orders(all_results, k)
    )
})

do.call(grid.arrange, c(unlist(plots, recursive = FALSE), ncol = 2))


Based on these results, we can see that on average, the same queue with 4 servers outperforms the 3 server queue for cumulative orders processed and queue length - but somehow the percent of customers waiting longer than 15 minutes is better (i.e. increases slower) for 3 servers than 4 servers?
From a theoretical computer science perspective, is this possible? Or have I made a mistake in this?

Please describe in words what your computational model is.

Good question. Can you provide some explanation of the code? It seems that the server protocol is contained in the code, but it is not entirely clear to me what the servers' protocol is. Are customers served first come - first serve? A trivial observation: A configuration with 4 servers can always emulate 3 servers by artificially forcing one server to remain idle. If that 4th server is then turned on and does any work, you would expect it to be a bonus with no disadvantages. (But it sounds like you've already figured that out)

Your intution is correct: If the customers are served on a first come, first serve basis, then adding more servers should not increase the percent of customers waiting longer than any fixed $t$ amount of time.
Let me sketch the reasoning without giving a formal proof.
Imagine 3 servers (or cashiers, if you prefer a visual metaphor) servicing customers who wait in one shared FIFO queue. If a thousand customers come, each customer $j$ waits for some time $t_j\geq 0$. From the perspective of the first 3 servers, adding an extra server has the effect of periodically removing the first customer from the queue. This action is independent of the 3 servers, who will continue processing their customers as before. No customer will ever have to wait longer because of this.
An exception is if the customers file in 4 different queues, one for each server. Then the 4th server may cause much waiting time if it gets unlucky and receives many customers that require lots of time (or if the server itself is slower than the others). But my reading of your question is that this is not the case.

Therefore, I recommend that you do the following things (among others) to check your code for bugs

For just 1 simulation run for each configuration, print the time at which each customer is serviced, and by which server. Inspect these 2 lists manually and double-check that it checks out. Something should be amiss here.
Do not generate the customer list during simulation, not even using a known random seed; instead, write the customer list to a file once; then read in the same file in both configurations. The .csv file format lends itself well for this purpose. Generate many files with different random customer lists
Double-check that you are giving the same customer list to both configurations
After you change some code, it is possible that it is still wrong but by coincidence produces an expected result for the cases $n=3,4$ servers. You can prevent this by repeating the experiment for $n=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots, 20$ servers. Compare the resulting graphs for waiting time. Does the pattern of "more servers = worse waiting time" persist? If so, you have not yet solved the bug. (You can even automate this as a test)
plot your graphs of $n=3,4$ using the same y-axis
keep in mind that the bug may be in one or more of several different places:

the logic with which the servers accept new customers in run_simulation
the way the data is logged
the code that collects the data, in process_results



My guess is that the logic of the servers is working correctly, since adding an extra service increases throughput. Therefore, my guess is that the bug is in the way the data is logged or collected.
Good luck.
